Looking for a highest weight vector of $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb C)$ with specific properties
Let $W = V \oplus V^*$, where $V = \langle a_1,...,a_n \rangle$ is the standard $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ representation and $V^* = \langle b_1,..., b_n \rangle$ is its dual. We can view $W$ as the standard $\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}(\mathbb C)$ representation. Letting $\mu$ be the symplectic form with $\mu(a_i,b_i)=1$, there exists a map $$C: \bigwedge^3 W \rightarrow W $$ such that $$C_3(x \wedge y \wedge z) = \mu(x,y)z + \mu(y,z)x + \mu(z,x)y.$$
$\operatorname{ker}(C_3)$ is the irreducible $\mathfrak{sp}_{2n}(\mathbb C)$ representation $\Gamma_{0,0,1}$.
I'm looking for a highest weight vector $v \in \bigwedge^2 \bigwedge^3 W$ that satisfies the following properies:

$v$ is in $\bigwedge^2 \operatorname{ker}(C_3)$
$v$ is in the kernel of the map $\bigwedge^2 \bigwedge^3 W \rightarrow \bigwedge^6 W$ given by $(a \wedge b \wedge c) \wedge (d \wedge e \wedge f) \mapsto a \wedge b \wedge c \wedge d \wedge e \wedge f$
$v$ has $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb C)$ weight $(1,0,1,0,...,0)$, or $2t_1 + t_2 + t_3$.

An example of a vector that satisfies all of the above properties except for being a highest weight vector is $(a_1 \wedge a_2 \wedge a_4) \wedge (a_1 \wedge a_3 \wedge b_4)$. How can I go about finding a highest weight vector? I know it exists because $\Gamma_{0,1,0,1} \subset \bigwedge^2 \Gamma_{0,0,1}$ contains a copy of the $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb C)$ representation with highest weight $(1,0,1,0,...,0)$ (I branched it in LiE).

I assume your $V$ is a vector space and not only ${ a_1, \dots, a_n }$?

Oops yes, that's a basis. I'll edit that
